# Power flow analysis issue

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-flow-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe6G78.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to get the hang of power flow analysis and I can't figure out how to measure the power (P and Q) between two inductances.

[E source] ---> [L inductance] ---> measurement ---> [L inductance] -----> [U source]

```
Q   =   ((E^2)/(X))-((E*U)/(X))*cosd(PhaseE-PhaseU);
Q   =   ((E*U)/X)*cosd(PhaseE-PhaseU) - (U^2)/X
```

[Edit to be reviewed by OP.]

$$    Q   =   \frac {E^2}{X} - \frac {E \cdot U}{X}cos(phaseE - phaseU) $$
$$    Q   =   \frac {E \cdot U}{X}cos(phaseU - phaseE) - \frac {U^2}{X} $$

[End of edit.]

These formulas doesn't cut it because they give the result for either end but not the middle.

Do I need to add something to my formula?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There's a built-in schematic tool on the editor toolbar. You should add a schematic. The site also supports [MathJAX](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) if you want to make it more readable.

Comment: I added MathJAX for you. See if it's what you intended. What is "*cosd*"?

Comment: Thanks, cosd is cosinus but for degrees instead of radians in matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, there will be no P consumed or delivered if you consider the inductances to be ideal.

You can work out the voltage at the node between the 2 inductances.
If you assign a name to the node (I've called it n) between the 2 inductances you can get some formulas to work out the voltage at that node. Being that it is a series circuit you can work out the current also. Then voltage x current... This would give you the power flowing through the node n,

$$ \frac{V_1\angle\theta_1 - V_n\angle\theta_n}{Z_{L1}\angle 90^\circ} = \frac { V_n\angle\theta_n - V_2\angle\theta_2} {Z_{L2}\angle 90^\circ}  $$

Rearrange this and solve for $$ V_n\angle\theta_n $$

For power flow analysis what you've presented would be fairly uncommon in practice. It would make more sense if there was a load at the node n and you were trying to work out what was being delivered to that load. The text book I have is called Power System Analysis and Design by Glover, Sarma and Overbye. It has been a good reference for me in the years since I graduated also.

I hope this was helpful. (The polar notation is a personal preference of mine)